# CollectionView with background Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use collectionView with a transparent background and imageView under the CollectionView.  I change the ImageView depending on the cell that is in the middle, but the image are not displayed correctly, how you can solve it, an example of how it should look and looks below

**Gif:**

how it should work:

[image]

how it works:

[image]

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionViewRecomend.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomPagerViewCell

        let m = modals[indexPath.item]

        cell?.ImageView.image = m.image
        cell?.ImageView.backgroundColor = .white
        cell?.Name.text = m.name
        cell?.descriptions.text = m.description
        cell?.Folowers.text = String(m.folower)
        cell?.Publish.text = String(m.publish)

        ImageSlider.image = modals[indexPath.row].image



        cell?.liking = { (cells) in

            if cell?.like.tintColor == UIColor(hex: 0xD1D1D1, alpha: 1) {
                cell?.like.tintColor = UIColor.orange
                self.favorite(cell: cell ?? UITableViewCell())
            } else {
                cell?.like.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD1D1D1, alpha: 1)
                self.favorite(cell: cell ?? UITableViewCell())
            }

        }

        return cell!


}
```

**CollectionViewCell**

```
class CustomPagerViewCell: UICollectionViewCell  {

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptions: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Publish: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Folowers: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var BG: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var like: UIButton!
@objc var liking: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> Void)?
@IBAction func like(_ sender: Any) {
   liking?(self)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    like.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD1D1D1, alpha: 1)


    ImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    ImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD4D4D4, alpha: 1).cgColor
    ImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true


}
```

**insetForSectionAt**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        let cellWidth : CGFloat = self.collectionViewMenu.frame.width/1.2
        let numberOfCells = floor(self.view.frame.size.width / cellWidth)
        let edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * cellWidth)) / (numberOfCells + 1)

        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewRecomend.frame.height - 165, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)


}
```

**CollectionViewFlowLayout**

```
class CenterCellCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    if let cv = self.collectionView {

        let cvBounds = cv.bounds
        let halfWidth = cvBounds.size.width * 0.5;
        let proposedContentOffsetCenterX = proposedContentOffset.x + halfWidth;

        if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: cvBounds) {

            var candidateAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
            for attributes in attributesForVisibleCells {

                // == Skip comparison with non-cell items (headers and footers) == //
                if attributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategory.cell {
                    continue
                }

                if let candAttrs = candidateAttributes {

                    let a = attributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX
                    let b = candAttrs.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX

                    if fabsf(Float(a)) < fabsf(Float(b)) {
                        candidateAttributes = attributes;
                    }

                }
                else { // == First time in the loop == //

                    candidateAttributes = attributes;
                    continue;
                }


            }

            return CGPoint(x : candidateAttributes!.center.x - halfWidth, y : proposedContentOffset.y);

        }

    }

    // Fallback
    return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset)
 }
}
```